# How are my arrays modified when C passes by value?

Tags: c

I made a simple program in C to check if two words are anagrams. My question is that if I'm passing word_one and word_two as parameters, doesn't that mean that I'm not modifying the original arrays? I would think that I'm effectively working on a copy of these which are not returned.

That means I shouldn't be able to compare them with my equal_array function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXLENGTH ((int) (sizeof(letters) / sizeof(letters[0])))

void read_word(int counts[26]);
bool equal_array(int counts[26], int counts2[26]);

int main(void){

  int word_one[26] = { 0 };
  int word_two[26] = { 0 };

  printf("Enter first word: ");
  read_word(word_one); 

  printf("Enter second word: ");
  read_word(word_two); 

  if (equal_array(word_one, word_two))
    printf("These words are anagrams!");
  else
    printf("These words not are anagrams!");

  return 0;
}

void read_word(int counts[26]){
  char ch;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
    ch = toupper(ch);
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
      counts[(ch - 'A')]++;
    } 
  }
}

bool equal_array(int counts1[26], int counts2[26]){
    int i;
    bool equal = true;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
      if (counts1[i] != counts2[i]) {
        equal = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return equal;
}
```

Comment: Aside: `char ch;` ==> `int ch;` because the return values / arguments for the functions used are of type `int`. Even `'A'` is of type `int`.

Comment: Arrays are passed by pointers in C.

Comment: The array is passed to the function as a pointer and each element can be changed.

Comment: The C language does not have string "values". When you pass a "string" to a function, what you're really passing is (a local copy of) the memory address at which the string starts. It then assumes that the character values at that location and following ones up to a terminating 0 are your string.

Comment: `void read_word(int counts[26])` is equivalent to `void read_word(int* counts)` , arguments cannot be arrays, they will always decay to pointers.

Comment: The array passed to a function decays to a pointer, so although the function argument is `int counts[26]` it behaves as `int *counts` and takes no notice of the length `26` (unless a 2D array).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C indeed always passes by value, but when arrays are passed to functions they **always** decay to pointers, even when you specify the length in the parameter declaration. What happens is that your declaration of

```
void read_word(int counts[26])
```

is equivalent to

```
void read_word(int * counts)
```

When you pass `word_one` and `word_two` to your functions, the value they recieve is the address of the first element of the array. These still point to the original arrays and therefore, when you modify them in the function, the result is also visible in the original array.

**ADDIT**

Interesting, but little-known side note: in C99 and beyond you can declare your functions with the length preceded by `static`, as follows:

```
void read_word(int counts[static 26])
```

This doesn't change the fact that the function receives a copy of the address and not the whole array, but it does allow the compiler to optimize and detect potential errors. In the case of the `read_word` above, the compiler can warn if you pass a `NULL`-pointer to the function, or an array with less than 26 elements. More can be read [here](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html).

Comment: Unsurprisingly, MSVC will not compile `void read_word(int counts[static 26])`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The following [program](https://ideone.com/I2CfhK) compiles [with errors too](https://pastebin.com/raw/Wmm7dhrc). It is a good thing I guess to take benefit of this.

Answer (score 4):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you call

```
read_word(word_one);
```

The *expression* `word_one` is converted from type "26-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", so what actually gets passed to `read_word` is the *address* of the first element of `word_one`.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both interpreted as `T *a` - `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.  Thus, the prototype

```
void read_word(int counts[26])
```

is interpreted as

```
void read_word(int *counts)
```

Thus, `read_word` does indeed modify the contents of `word_one` and `word_two`.

You'll want to pass the size of the array as a separate parameter:

```
read_word( word_one, sizeof word_one );
...
void read_word( int *counts, size_t size )
{
  ...
}
```

since you won't know how big the target array is from the pointer alone.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are reference types in C. If a function takes an array, it will be passed a pointer, and any changes you make to it will also affect the original array.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I must have missed that in the book I'm reading from.

Comment: The closest thing to _reference types_  mentioned in the Standard is [_referenced type_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20) but this pertains to pointers, not arrays. [Arrays are _derived types_, and also _aggregate types_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20); an array is not a pointer, but "a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type".

Answer (score -2):

C passes only the pointer. Only structs and simple types are passed by the value.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters, but in C _everything_ is passed by value. An array decays to a pointer to its first element in most expressions, including function calls, and it is this pointer that is passed by value to the function.